# Flurry Ads on Unity3D with Prime31 plugin

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, flurry, prime31

I am trying to implement Ads with Flurry using the plugin for Unity from Prime31. I think everything is set right, but I still have problems getting ads to show.

I have tried setting test ads a both, true and false, but I still cant properly get ads to show. Most of the time I get one ad at the beginning of the day and after that, the plugin tells me it failed to get an ad and I get this:

```
06-09 10:20:11.540: E/FlurryAgent(1163): Ad server responded but sent no ad units.
```

From FlurryAgent.

Most of the time I have tried with test ads enabled and I have gotten banner ads and fullscreen video ads. Sometimes the ad is just a small blue pulsing rectangle and sometimes it is some ad for a random game. I tought the blue rectangle to be a test ad, but I am still getting normal ads when test ads are enabled and most of the time there is no ad at all.